# Serialize increasing Size

Tags: c#, oracle, serialization, clob

I am serializing `SessionStateItemCollection items`, the length of my string is more than 12000 character is there any way to compress size of string.

Here is my code please one can help me to resolve this issue.

```
 private string Serialize(SessionStateItemCollection items)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms);

        if (items.Count != 0)
            items.Serialize(writer);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ms.Length);
        writer.Close();

       return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Why is more than 12000 character a problem? What does your question have to do with Oracle?

Comment: basically that is problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211163/string-literal-too-long-for-clob-type/17211561#17211561

Comment: You can try compressing, see the answers to [Compress and decompress a Stream with Compression.DeflateStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10599596/3744182).